# How can I create optional leading path parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to have an optional path prefix. Ideally, this would allow me to create the optional path and a parameter.

For example:

I have the route `"/search"`, but I would like this route to match for both `"/search"` as well as `"/portal/somePortalID/search"` and have `somePortalID` available to me in the child props.

So far I have tried:

`<Route path="(/portal/:portalId)?/search">`

`<Route path="(/:portalId(/portal/\.+)?/search">`

Bonus points if you could include an idea as to how to dynamically change the children React Router `<Link />` components so they include the optional prefix to keep the user within that route.

I'm using `react-router@5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below Route

```
<Route path="(/portal/:portalId/search" component={yourComponent} >
<Route path="(/portal/example/search/" component={yourComponent} >
<Route path="(/search" component={yourComponent} >
```

Please Note you can route to the same component with different routes

Comment: This does not seem to match the `/search` or `/portal/example/search/` routes unfortunately

Comment: I would really like to avoid separate hard-coded routes for each component as these routes will be littered in many places in the application and I am looking for a more maintainable approach. I would also like to keep the `:portalId` dynamic as there will eventually be many of them.

Comment: yes in this case your portal id could be dynamic only. But I beleive you cannot have a single route to address both /porta/example/search and /search. It has to be two different routes. Or else you can configure it like /portal/*/search